# Adding time elapsed to a canvas game in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with integrating a simple timer to a game I am trying to build for a practice exercise. I have attempted to search for this solution on the internet but my basic knowledge of .js leaves me stuck at this problem. Can anyone help me with a solution to this?

My codepen is located here: https://codepen.io/jankyvision/pen/PoqYEXV

```
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 720; 
c.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(c);

var perm = [];
while (perm.length < 255){
    while(perm.includes(val = Math.floor(Math.random()*255)));
    perm.push(val);
}

var lerp = (a,b,t) => a + (b-a) * (1-Math.cos(t*Math.PI))/2;
var noise = x=>{
    x = x * 0.01 % 254;
    return lerp(perm[Math.floor(x)], perm[Math.ceil(x)], x - Math.floor(x));
}

var Player =  function(){
    this.x = c.width/2;
    this.y = 0;
    this.ySpeed = 0;
    this.rot = 0;
    this.rSpeed = 0;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = "./images/moto.png";
    this.draw = function(){
        var p1 =  c.height - noise(t + this.x) * 0.25;
        var p2 =  c.height - noise(t+5 + this.x) * 0.25;

        var grounded = 0;
        if(p1-12 > this.y){
            this.ySpeed += 0.1;
        }else{
            this.ySpeed -= this.y - (p1-12);
            this.y = p1 - 12;
            grounded = 1;
        }

        var angle = Math.atan2((p2-12) - this.y, (this.x+5) - this.x);
        this.y += this.ySpeed;

        if(!playing || grounded && Math.abs(this.rot) > Math.PI * 0.5){
            playing = false;
            this.rSpeed = 5;
            k.ArrowUp = 1;
            this.x -= speed * 5;
        }


        if(grounded && playing){
            this.rot -= (this.rot - angle) * 0.65;
            this.rSpeed = this.rSpeed - (angle - this.rot);
        }
        this.rSpeed += (k.ArrowLeft - k.ArrowRight) * 0.05;
        this.rot -= this.rSpeed * 0.1;
        if(this.rot > Math.PI) this.rot = -Math.PI;
        if(this.rot < -Math.PI) this.rot = Math.PI;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y - 3);
        ctx.rotate(this.rot);
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, -15, -15, 60, 30);
        ctx.restore();
    }
}

var player = new Player();
var t = 0;
var speed = 0;
var playing = true;
var k = {ArrowUp:0, ArrowDown:0, ArrowLeft:0, ArrowRight:0};
function loop(){
    speed -= (speed - (k.ArrowUp - k.ArrowDown)) * 0.01;
    t += 10 * speed;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8D5BC2";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width, c.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, c.height);
    for (let i = 0; i < c.width; i++)
        ctx.lineTo(i, c.height*0.8 - noise(t + i*5) * 0.25);
    ctx.lineTo(c.width, c.height);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle = "#444";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, c.height);
    for (let i = 0; i < c.width; i++)
        ctx.lineTo(i, c.height - noise(t + i) * 0.25);
    ctx.lineTo(c.width, c.height);
    ctx.fill();

    player.draw();
    if(player.x < 0)
        restart();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

onkeydown = d=> k[d.key] = 1;
onkeyup = d=> k[d.key] = 0;

function restart(){

    player = new Player();
    t = 0;
    speed = 0;
    playing = true;
    k = {ArrowUp:0, ArrowDown:0, ArrowLeft:0, ArrowRight:0};

}
loop();

var instructions = document.createElement("div");
instructions.innerHTML += "[up] [down] = accelerate <br> [Left] [Rigth] = rotate";
document.body.appendChild(instructions);
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly, I didn't get your problem, do you mean just adding seconds timer to the game canvas/HTML?

Comment: @mamounothman, yes I would like to add a seconds timer for when the game starts and i want that timer to restart when the game restarts too.

Answer (score 1):

With some help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16255190/1309377 you are looking at a pretty simple function that uses `ctx.fillText()` to draw the amount of elapsed seconds onto the canvas.

You want to use the `Date()` object when doing a timer as it is more accurate than setTimeout or setInterval.

On restart you just set `startTime` to the current time again.

```js
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var startTime = new Date();
c.width = 720;
c.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(c);

var perm = [];
while (perm.length < 255) {
  while (perm.includes(val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)));
  perm.push(val);
}

var lerp = (a, b, t) => a + (b - a) * (1 - Math.cos(t * Math.PI)) / 2;
var noise = x => {
  x = x * 0.01 % 254;
  return lerp(perm[Math.floor(x)], perm[Math.ceil(x)], x - Math.floor(x));
}

function drawElapsedTime() {
  var elapsed = parseInt((new Date() - startTime) / 1000);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.font = "14px Verdana"
  // draw the running time at half opacity
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.50;
  ctx.fillText(elapsed + " seconds", 30,30);
  ctx.restore();
}

var Player = function() {
  this.x = c.width / 2;
  this.y = 0;
  this.ySpeed = 0;
  this.rot = 0;
  this.rSpeed = 0;
  this.img = new Image();
  this.img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3b/SpongeBob_SquarePants_character.svg";
  this.draw = function() {
    var p1 = c.height - noise(t + this.x) * 0.25;
    var p2 = c.height - noise(t + 5 + this.x) * 0.25;

    var grounded = 0;
    if (p1 - 12 > this.y) {
      this.ySpeed += 0.1;
    } else {
      this.ySpeed -= this.y - (p1 - 12);
      this.y = p1 - 12;
      grounded = 1;
    }

    var angle = Math.atan2((p2 - 12) - this.y, (this.x + 5) - this.x);
    this.y += this.ySpeed;

    if (!playing || grounded && Math.abs(this.rot) > Math.PI * 0.5) {
      playing = false;
      this.rSpeed = 5;
      k.ArrowUp = 1;
      this.x -= speed * 5;
    }


    if (grounded && playing) {
      this.rot -= (this.rot - angle) * 0.65;
      this.rSpeed = this.rSpeed - (angle - this.rot);
    }
    this.rSpeed += (k.ArrowLeft - k.ArrowRight) * 0.05;
    this.rot -= this.rSpeed * 0.1;
    if (this.rot > Math.PI) this.rot = -Math.PI;
    if (this.rot < -Math.PI) this.rot = Math.PI;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y - 3);
    ctx.rotate(this.rot);
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, -15, -15, 60, 30);
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

var player = new Player();
var t = 0;
var speed = 0;
var playing = true;
var k = {
  ArrowUp: 0,
  ArrowDown: 0,
  ArrowLeft: 0,
  ArrowRight: 0
};

function loop() {
  speed -= (speed - (k.ArrowUp - k.ArrowDown)) * 0.01;
  t += 10 * speed;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#8D5BC2";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, c.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < c.width; i++)
    ctx.lineTo(i, c.height * 0.8 - noise(t + i * 5) * 0.25);
  ctx.lineTo(c.width, c.height);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.fillStyle = "#444";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, c.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < c.width; i++)
    ctx.lineTo(i, c.height - noise(t + i) * 0.25);
  ctx.lineTo(c.width, c.height);
  ctx.fill();

  player.draw();
  drawElapsedTime();
  if (player.x < 0)
    restart();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

onkeydown = d => k[d.key] = 1;
onkeyup = d => k[d.key] = 0;

function restart() {
  
  player = new Player();
  startTime = new Date();
  t = 0;
  speed = 0;
  playing = true;
  k = {
    ArrowUp: 0,
    ArrowDown: 0,
    ArrowLeft: 0,
    ArrowRight: 0
  };

}
loop();

var instructions = document.createElement("div");
instructions.innerHTML += "[up] [down] = accelerate <br> [Left] [Rigth] = rotate";
document.body.appendChild(instructions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var secs = 0;
setInterval(function(){secs++},1000);
```

```
this.draw = function(){

  // Fill in a rectangle to put the time inside of
  ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(10,10,55,25);

  ctx.fillStyle="#8D5BC2";
  ctx.font = "12px";

  // Format the number of seconds - 0:00
  timestr = Math.floor(secs/60) + ":";
  timestr += ((secs%60<10)&&"0") + secs%60;

  // Write the time string over the rectangle
  ctx.fillText(timestr,25,25);
```

Comment: Hi Kevin Morey, can you please clarify how I would implement your code above?

Comment: I edited my reply to show you the fillRect and fillText parts should go at the beginning of your this.draw function